# Сохранение переменных, результатов

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Требуется сохранять некоторое значение после завершения приложения и в дальнейшем подгружать его, например рекорд или кол-во очков. В `Unity` есть прекрасный инструмент `PlayerPrefs` (сохраняет пару "ключ-значение"). Есть ли что-то подобное в Android Studio? Или может либа какая-то? Спасибо.

Comment: sharedpreferences

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Записать в общие настройки**

Для записи в файл общих настроек создайте объект `SharedPreferences.Editor` посредством вызова `edit()` в `SharedPreferences`.

Передайте ключи и значения, которые хотите записать, с помощью таких методов, как `putInt()` и `putString()`. Затем вызовите `commit()` для сохранения изменений. Например:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

---

**Прочитать из общих настроек**

Для получения значений из файла общих настроек следует вызвать такие, методы как `getInt()` и `getString()`, предоставляя ключ для нужного вам значения, а также при желании значение по умолчанию, которое будет выводиться при отсутствии ключа. Например:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

[Источник](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#ReadSharedPreference)